# How to check menu item in Android Navigation Drawer Template?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm using 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1' in my application; therefore, I generated a Navigation Drawer selecting it in the UI.

However, when I click in one item of the menu, it is not getting checked. Below is my code!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    Fragment fragment = new PainelFragment();
    replaceFragment(fragment);
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    Fragment fragment = null;

    if (id == R.id.nav_painel) {
        // Handle the painel action
        fragment = new PainelFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_modelos) {
        // Handle the modelos action
        fragment = new TabsFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_cronograma) {
        // Handle the cronograma action
        fragment = new TabsFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_faleConosco) {
        // Handle the fale conosco action
        fragment = new FaleConoscoFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_perfil) {
        // Handle the perfil action
        fragment = new PerfilFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_configuracoes) {
        // Handle the configuracoes action
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    //replacing the fragment
    if (fragment != null) {
        replaceFragment(fragment);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private void replaceFragment(Fragment f) {
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_main, f)
        .commit();
}
}
```

Comment: post error log here

Comment: It does not show any error